# Pandas, Exclude value from column using ~.isin: Type Error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter the word "No" out of multiple columns in my dataframe.

I am getting error  `TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]`

Code:

```
answerlist = ('No')
gcofilter = gcofile[~gcofile[column_a].isin(answerlist) & ~gcofile[column_b].isin(answerlist) & ~gcofile[column_c].isin(answerlist)]
```

Is there a way around this? I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `answerlist` as a list instead:

```
answerlist = ['No']

gcofilter = gcofile[~gcofile[column_a].isin(answerlist) & ~gcofile[column_b].isin(answerlist) & ~gcofile[column_c].isin(answerlist)]
```

Additionally, if your `column_a`, `column_b`, `column_c` are actually column names instead of variable names storing column names, you should also put them within quotes, as follows:

```
answerlist = ['No']

gcofilter = gcofile[~gcofile['column_a'].isin(answerlist) & ~gcofile['column_b'].isin(answerlist) & ~gcofile['column_c'].isin(answerlist)]
```

Comment: im so dumb, thanks.

Comment: @Jonnyboi  We are all sometimes making such minor mistakes.  It's common!

Comment: thanks had another question that is related, if I dont want to pass "No" into the list, how can I pass values from another column as `answerlist`?

Comment: @Jonnyboi  `.isin()` supports also a column, you can use e.g. `.isin(gcofile['column_x'])` for it.

Comment: @Jonnyboi  It even accept column from another dataframe too!  It just treat the values of that column like a list.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a comma

```
answerlist = ('No',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a python list instead of tuple and parentheses to separate your conditions.

```
answerlist = ['No']
gcofilter = gcofile[(~gcofile[column_a].isin(answerlist)) & (~gcofile[column_b].isin(answerlist)) & (~gcofile[column_c].isin(answerlist))]
```